# jQuery: How can I hide a category from the Show All option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, tumblr

I am using a layout on the blog website Tumblr. I'd like to remove the "Childhood Influences" category from the Show All feature. I've only managed to remove it from the front page, but I would like the Childhood Influences to only show up when you click on its tab. Here's the code:

```
<!-- 

CURRENTLY WATCHING #2
pistachi-o (nutty-themes @ tumblr)

Theme Documentation:
http://nutty-themes.tumblr.com/themedoc

Please Do Not:
http://nutty-themes.tumblr.com/terms

-->

<head>

<title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="altertnate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">

<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">

/* Reset ----------------------------- */

body,div,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,th,td {margin:0;padding:0;}

/* Scrollbar ----------------------------- */

::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 6px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: #FFF;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #DDD;}

/* General ----------------------------- */

body {
background: #f3f3f3;
font-size: 10px;
color: #000000;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 100%; 
}

a:link, a:active, a:visited {
color: #130912;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #f38335;
text-decoration: none;
}

b {
color: #f7941d;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Isotope (DO NOT EDIT) ----------------------------- */

.isotope-item {
z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
pointer-events: none;
z-index: 1;
}

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
-webkit-hiatus-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-hiatus-duration: 0.8s;
hiatus-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
-webkit-hiatus-property: height, width;
-moz-hiatus-property: height, width;
hiatus-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
-webkit-hiatus-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
-moz-hiatus-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
hiatus-property: transform, opacity;
}

/* Navigation ----------------------------- */

#shows {
position: relative; 
width: 100%; 
height: 10px; 
margin: 0px auto 10px; 
background: blue; 
padding: 15px 0px; 
background: #fafafa;
text-align: center; 
}

/* Contents ----------------------------- */

#container {
width: 840px;
position: relative; 
text-align: center; 
margin: 50px auto; 
}

#containers {
width: 840px;
position: relative; 
text-align: center; 
margin: 50px auto; 
}

#nextcontainer {
width: 840px;
position: relative; 
text-align: center; 
margin: 50px auto; 
}

#nextcontainers {
width: 840px;
position: relative; 
text-align: center; 
margin: 50px auto; 
}

.stylewrap {
background: #edd456;
width: 200px;
height: 165px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.hiatus {
background: #a0c1ba;
}

.complete {
background: #45c0ab;
}

.childhood {
background: #e3e3e3;
}

.next {
background: #c6c6c6;
}

.stylewrap  img {
margin: 0;
width: 200px; 
border-bottom: 2px solid #F3F3F3; 
}

h2 {
margin: 10px 0px 3px; 
line-height: 100%; 
}

#filters {
text-transform: uppercase; 
}

#filters li {
display: inline; 
margin: 2px; 
padding: 2px 5px; 
}

#dash {
text-transform: uppercase; 
margin: 25px; 
}

#dash li {
display: inline; 
margin: 2px; 
padding: 2px 5px; 
}


.stylewrap:hover .grey {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);  
}

</style>  
</head>

<body>

<div id="shows">
<ul id="filters" class="show-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">Show All</a></li>
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".current">Currently Watching</a></li>
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".hiatus">On Hiatus</a></li>
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".complete">Completed</a></li>
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".next">Next Up</a></li>
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".childhood">Childhood Influences</a></a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="dash">
<li><a href="/">Back Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://tumblr.com/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="http://nutty-themes.tumblr.com/">Theme Credits</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id="container">


<!-- To add completed show copy and paste the following -->
<div class="stylewrap next">
<img class="grey" src="http://imgur.com/Bktk9mC.jpg">
<h2 class="name"><a href="/tagged/">6teen</a></h2>
Up Next
</div>
<!-- End of Complete Show -->


<div class="stylewrap current">
<img class="grey" src="http://imgur.com/IO7NGnK.jpg" />
<h2 class="name"><a href="/tagged/18_to_life">18 to Life</a></h2>
Season 2 Episode 11
</div>


<div class="stylewrap childhood">
<img class="grey" src="http://imgur.com/NTMO0xq.jpg">
<h2 class="name"><a href="/tagged/">7th Heaven</a></h2>
(1996-2007)
</div>


<!-- To add completed show copy and paste the following -->
<div class="stylewrap complete">
<img class="grey" src="http://imgur.com/vPkxn7c.jpg">
<h2 class="name"><a href="/tagged/">About a Girl</a></h2>
(2007-2008)
</div>
<!-- End of Complete Show -->


<!-- To add hiatus show copy and paste the following -->
<div class="stylewrap hiatus">
<img class="grey" src="http://imgur.com/owiMXh5.jpg">
<h2 class="name"><a href="/tagged/">Awkward.</a></h2>
Returning September 23, 2014
</div>
<!-- End of Hiatus Show -->



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/whx9ghv/1eGm9d17y/isotope.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.isotope({
      itemSelector : '.stylewrap',
      filter: '.current, .hiatus, .next, .complete',

      getSortData : {
        name : function ( $elem ) {
          return $elem.find('.name').text();
        }
      }
    });


      var $optionSets = $('#shows .show-set'),
          $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

      $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;

        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.show-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');


        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
        var options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');

        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[ key ] = value;
        if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
          // changes in layout modes need extra logic
          changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
        } else {
          // otherwise, apply new options
          $container.isotope( options );
          filter: '.current, .hiatus, .next, .complete';
        }

        return false;
      });


  });
</script>





</body>
</html>
```

I believe the problem is in the jQuery, but I just can't figure it out. I've spent 2 days on this, but I'm not too advanced so I've just been searching everywhere I can for an answer.

edit: Sorry for being unclear. The problem is solved!

Comment: I added an answer, but its difficult to guess what you're trying to do without a demonstration of what its doing so far.  Do you have a link to the content you're trying to modify?  And could you provide a better description of what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: You've received a number of answers at this point. If one of them correctly solves your problem, please click the checkmark next to it to mark the question as answered. Otherwise, it would be helpful if you commented on some of the answers (or edited your question) if none of them are satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...not sure if this is the best way, but you could simply alter the `data-option-value` attribute for the Show All option to omit `childhood` from the selector. You HTML might then become:

```
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*:not(.childhood)" class="selected">Show All</a></li>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8FDw/1/) to show you the code in action. Now clicking "Show All" will not reveal the item tagged with `childhood`. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but I believe you're asking how to remove a certain element from your unordered list.

This line:

```
<li style="background: #f5f5f5;"><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".childhood">Childhood Influences</a></a></li>
```

represents a list element with a text value of "Childhood Influences".  Remove the line, and this list item will no longer show up.

Edit: I misread your question, give me a second and I will edit this answer again to address your entire question correctly